# Are there any calculations that "backup" magnetized inertial fusion by steam pistons?

Tags: kinematics, fusion, nuclear-engineering

[Piston driven MTF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetized_target_fusion) can generate fusion. General Fusion has released data on the plasma confinement that they do in their machines, so there is no doubt to the feasibility of the approach.

Nonetheless, it does still seem absurd as a method to reach logically, alone would not expect to reach the demanding conditions to reach fusion by pistons. I imagine that before engaging in this endeavour, simulations or calculation were made that made such an approach possible.

Are there any documents, simulations or calculations that demonstrate that physically it is possible to reach these conditions with their pistons? Trying to understand the mechanism and forces acting in their reactor, specifically the piston section.

Answer (score 0):

The popular science accounts of the General Fusion approach can give the impression that pistons powered by steam are used to simply squeeze the deuterium tritium plasma until it fuses, and you are quite correct that this would not work.

In the GF reactor the pistons should be thought of as more like steam powered hammers. The plasma is contained inside a sphere of liquid metal, and the pistons strike the outer surface of the sphere and generate a shock wave. The shock wave propagates radially inwards and at the centre of the liquid metal sphere the shock waves converge to produce a pressure high enough to ignite fusion.

The approach is a form of inertial confinement, where it's the inertia of the liquid metal moving inwards that produces the conditions required for fusion.

The use of the phrase *steam piston* inspires images of some vaguely Victorian [steampunk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steampunk) apparatus. Steam is used because the heat produced by the fusion would be used to heat steam to power turbines, as in conventional power stations, so superheated steam is available and is a convenient way to power the hammers.

Comment: Absolutely, however the pistons is the main actor proving the force and pressure to the fuel. The liquid metal is there to absorb the heat to avoid radiation damage to the reactor walls  and to breed tritium from lithium-6. The forces applied and at what rate is more of the nature I ask in the question. What values one calculates that would justify starting such a venture

Comment: @Evamentality "the pistons is the main actor proving the force and pressure to the fuel" - no that isn't true. The pistons "hammer" the outside of the sphere to generate a shock wave, and as the wave propagates inwards it converges so the energy density gets larger and larger. At the centre it's the liquid metal that applies the force to the hydrogen not the steam pistons. It's a form of inertial confinement where it's the inertia of the metal that compresses the fuel.

Comment: In any case, the main question is how much force is being delivered, and by proxy, what is the acceleration of the pistons and fluid. That is why I asked the the parameters/calculations in the reaction vessel.

Answer (score 0):

> Piston driven MTF can generate fusion

Well, they certainly *say* that. But to date, they have not *actually done so*.

The few actual fusion experiments (one?) they have done that I am aware of were not carried out inside one of these systems, but a custom-built rig using explosives. So I would be hesitant to say "can", more like "could, in theory".